# Reference only part of parent selector in LESS

Tags: css, less

I'm new to LESS, so there's a good chance the answer to this is obvious and I'm just not seeing it.

I have a situation where I want to be able to add certain combinations of classes and pseudoclasses to an element and then style its sibling element based on those cases. I'm trying to use nesting and the ampersand to not repeat the sibling element.

Here's what I started with. It works, but requires me to repeat the `sibling` element many times:

```
base {
    & + sibling {
        /* sel: base + sibling */
    }

    &.class1 {
        & + sibling {
            /* sel: base.class1 + sibling */
        }

        &.class2 + sibling {
            /* sel: base.class1.class2 + sibling */
        }
    }

    &.class3 + sibling {
        /* sel: base.class3 + sibling */
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried that didn't work in order to avoid repeating `sibling` constantly:

```
sibling {
    base + & {
        /* sel(expected): base + sibling
           sel(actual):   base + sibling
           SUCCESS */
        &.class1 {
            /* sel(expected): base.class1 + sibling
               sel(actual): base + sibling.class1
               FAILURE */

            &.class2 {
                /* sel(expected): base.class1.class2 + sibling
                   sel(actual): base + sibling.class1.class2
                   FAILURE */
            }
        }

        &.class3 {
            /* sel(expected): base.class3 + sibling
               sel(actual): base + sibling.class3
               FAILURE */
        }
    }
}
```

I understand why it didn't work, but I don't see a way in LESS to do this without repeating `sibling` all over the place, and it seems like it should be possible. Anyone smarter than me see something I'm missing?

Comment: I realize I could make a variable for `+ sibling` which would at least make it easy to replace, but it still seems like this should be solvable with nesting.

Comment: Well, no it's not possible. It's the same pitfall as always you expect the same feature to perform two (or even three) quite orthogonal things at once: 1. conbine selectors by nesting 2. ignore nesting when combining them 3. use nesting as repetition remover (in many cases incl. your particular example above it's simply impossible).

Comment: if your `base` was `.base` actually it would be possible though (since in CSS `.a.b.c` is equal to `.c.b.a` etc.): [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/6e4a8e7e6e30b34bc886). But it still would be nothing but a lucky coincidence.

Comment: Yeah, I get that the parent selector isn't the way to do this, it's just what I started messing around with. I guess my real question is: is there anything else in LESS that will let me make this more DRY? Maybe something with `extend()` (which I'm still sort of struggling to understand)?